# how to get data from separate columns in parse.com

Tags: android, database, parse-platform

I am new to parse.com and databases in general.

For my android app, I need to search if an object is available and if so, then it should give me its price. So my class is vegetables, and it has a column called 'isAvailable' and another column called 'price'

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("vegetables");
query.whereEqualTo("isAvailable", true); try {
    ob = query.find();
}
catch (ParseException e) {
    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

So, now I do have a list of all the vegetables that are available, but how do I query the price?
I was thinking of using the whereMatchesQuery(key, query) but it doesnt make too much sense on how to use it.

Could you guide me so as to what I should be doing, thanks !

Comment: Parse has very clear documentation on how queries work for Android here: https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#queries

Comment: They are useful, however without many tutorials and examples which makes them pretty hard to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So now you'll have a list of vegetables objects in ob.

Just iterate through ob pulling the price from each one in the list.

```
for(ParseObject vegetable : ob){
    Log.d("TAG", "price: " + vegetable.getDouble("price"))
}
```